# How to have the cursor at the right indentation when editing PHP/HTML

Tags: indentation, cursor, filetype-php

When I'm working with `HTML` in a `PHP` file and I press <kbd>enter</kbd> while in `INSERT` mode, my cursor goes to the start of the next line instead of going at the right positive therefore I have to press <kbd>tab</kbd> to position my cursor every time.

For example, I have the following in my `index.php` and my cursor is at the `_` position:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>_
```

If I press <kbd>enter</kbd> in `INSERT` mode, it becomes like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
_
```

Instead of this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        _
```

However, I do get the expected position when I modify a `HTML` file type.

Is there an option or plugin that change this behaviour?

Comment: Do you have [`:h 'autoindent'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27autoindent%27) set in your config? And also maybe [`:h 'smartindent'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27smartindent%27) and [`:h 'cindent'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27cindent%27)?

Comment: @statox No but `autoindent` is not doing what I want. It simply copies the indentation of the previous line.

Comment: I've also tried `cindent` and `smartindent` but they are both not working.

Comment: This answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/459478/4194289) suggest three things: either you change the file type to `set ft=phtml` and hope it gets better, or you only do `set ft=html` and `set ft=php` depending on what kind of code you are editing in your php file, or you give [this indent script](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Better_indent_support_for_php_with_html) a try.

Comment: Thanks the plugin is working! Do you want to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: If you want you can post the answer yourself, explaining why you think the plugin is a better option than the other ones. (And don't forget to self-accept your answer when you can :) )

Answer (score 1):

Using this [plugin](https://github.com/captbaritone/better-indent-support-for-php-with-html) solved the issue for me:

```
Plug 'captbaritone/better-indent-support-for-php-with-html', { 'for': 'php' }
```

It is better than switching between `php` and `html` file type in my scenario because I have linters. So the html linter will throw me **fake** errors for my php code.